# Google CodeJam Qualification Round: Bathroom stall

Tags: c++, algorithm, vectors

> Problem
>
> A certain bathroom has N + 2 stalls in a single row; the stalls on the
>   left and right ends are permanently occupied by the bathroom guards.
>   The other N stalls are for users.
>
> Whenever someone enters the bathroom, they try to choose a stall that
>   is as far from other people as possible. To avoid confusion, they
>   follow deterministic rules: For each empty stall S, they compute two
>   values LS and RS, each of which is the number of empty stalls between
>   S and the closest occupied stall to the left or right, respectively.
>   Then they consider the set of stalls with the farthest closest
>   neighbor, that is, those S for which min(LS, RS) is maximal. If there
>   is only one such stall, they choose it; otherwise, they choose the one
>   among those where max(LS, RS) is maximal. If there are still multiple
>   tied stalls, they choose the leftmost stall among those.
>
> K people are about to enter the bathroom; each one will choose their
>   stall before the next arrives. Nobody will ever leave.
>
> When the last person chooses their stall S, what will the values of
>   max(LS, RS) and min(LS, RS) be?
>
> Solving this problem
>
> This problem has 2 Small datasets and 1 Large dataset. You must solve
>   the first Small dataset before you can attempt the second Small
>   dataset. You will be able to retry either of the Small datasets (with
>   a time penalty). You will be able to make a single attempt at the
>   Large, as usual, only after solving both Small datasets.
>
> Input
>
> The first line of the input gives the number of test cases, T. T lines
>   follow. Each line describes a test case with two integers N and K, as
>   described above.
>
> Output
>
> For each test case, output one line containing Case #x: y z, where x
>   is the test case number (starting from 1), y is max(LS, RS), and z is
>   min(LS, RS) as calculated by the last person to enter the bathroom for
>   their chosen stall S.
>
> Limits
>
> - 1 ≤ T ≤ 100
> - 1 ≤ K ≤ N
> - Small dataset 1
> - 1 ≤ N ≤ 1000
> - Small dataset 2
> - 1 ≤ N ≤ \$10^6\$
> - Large dataset
> - 1 ≤ N ≤ \$10^{18}\$
>
> Sample Input       Output
>
> ```
> 5
> 4 2
> 5 2
> 6 2
> 1000 1000
> 1000 1
> ```
>
> - Case #1: 1 0
> - Case #2: 1 0
> - Case #3: 1 1
> - Case #4: 0 0
> - Case #5: 500 499
>
> In Case #1, the first person occupies the leftmost of the middle two
>   stalls, leaving the following configuration (O stands for an occupied
>   stall and . for an empty one): O.O..O. Then, the second and last
>   person occupies the stall immediately to the right, leaving 1 empty
>   stall on one side and none on the other.
>
> In Case #2, the first person occupies the middle stall, getting to
>   O..O..O. Then, the second and last person occupies the leftmost stall.
>
> In Case #3, the first person occupies the leftmost of the two middle
>   stalls, leaving O..O...O. The second person then occupies the middle
>   of the three consecutive empty stalls.
>
> In Case #4, every stall is occupied at the end, no matter what the
>   stall choices are.
>
> In Case #5, the first and only person chooses the leftmost middle
>   stall.

I could solve the inputs C-small-1 and C-small-2 efficiently but my code runs quite a while for input C-large. Are there any ways that I can improve this code?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

// Print queue
void print_q(std::priority_queue<vector<int>>& QQ)
{
    int num =0;
    while (!QQ.empty())
    {
        cout << "Accessing for " << num << " times" << endl;
        vector<int> temp = QQ.top();
        for (vector<int>::iterator it = temp.begin(); it != temp.end(); it++)
        {
            cout << *it << " ";
        }
        QQ.pop();
        num++;
    }
}

// Input: a priority queue
// Output: an updated priority with midpoint as occupied stall

void print_vec(vector<int>& vec)
{
    cout << "content of vec: ";
    for (vector<int>::iterator it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); it++)
    {
        cout << *it << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    ifstream myfile;
    myfile.open("./Desktop/codes/GooglecodejamQ2/C-small-practice-2.in");
    int num_case,num_stall,num_person;
    myfile >> num_case;
    cout << "Nm of cases: " << num_case << endl;

    while ( num_case!=0 )
    {

        myfile >> num_stall;
        myfile >> num_person;
        cout << num_stall <<  endl;


    struct CompareByLength {
        constexpr bool operator()(vector<int> const & a,
                                  vector<int> const & b) const noexcept
        {
            int aa = (a[1]-a[0])+1;
            int bb = (b[1]-b[0])+1;
            return aa < bb;

        }
    };

    std::priority_queue<vector<int>,vector<vector<int>>,CompareByLength> qq;
    vector <vector<int>> double_vec = {{1,num_stall}};
    for (vector<vector<int>>::iterator i = double_vec.begin(); i != double_vec.end(); i++)
    {
        qq.push(*i) ;
    }

    while (num_person != 0)
    {
        std::vector<int> tt = qq.top();
        qq.pop();

        int left = tt[0];
        int right = tt[1];

        int occ = tt[1] - ceil((double(tt[1])-double(tt[0]))/2);

        vector<int> l_stall = {left, occ-1};

        vector<int> r_stall = {occ+1, right};

        qq.push(l_stall);
        qq.push(r_stall);

        if(num_person ==1)
        {
            cout << "********** LAST PERSON CASE #" << 101- num_case <<" ***************" << endl;
            cout <<  "max(LS, RS)" << max((l_stall[1]-l_stall[0])+1,(r_stall[1]-r_stall[0])+1) << endl;
            cout <<  "min(LS, RS)" << min((l_stall[1]-l_stall[0])+1,(r_stall[1]-r_stall[0])+1) << endl;
        }
        num_person--;
        }
        num_case--;
    }
    myfile.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You might want to fix the formatting of your code. It looks like it goes bad around where you declare `struct CompareByLength`.

Answer (score 2):

For a start, 25% of that code is dead code: neither of the two debugging functions is actually called. I'm not going to bother reviewing them.

But I also see

> ```
>     myfile.open("./Desktop/codes/GooglecodejamQ2/C-small-practice-2.in");
> ```

and

> ```
>             cout << "********** LAST PERSON CASE #" << 101- num_case <<" ***************" << endl;
>             cout <<  "max(LS, RS)" << max((l_stall[1]-l_stall[0])+1,(r_stall[1]-r_stall[0])+1) << endl;
>             cout <<  "min(LS, RS)" << min((l_stall[1]-l_stall[0])+1,(r_stall[1]-r_stall[0])+1) << endl;
> ```

which isn't the correct output format, and breaks if the number of cases isn't 100.

In future please post your actual code for review, not a hacked debug version.

---

The indentation is rather messed up. I suspect the original code mixed tabs and spaces with a tabstop other than 4. StackExchange converts tabs to four spaces.

---

The whitespace doesn't seem particularly consistent. Compare, for example,

> ```
>   while ( num_case!=0 )
> ```

and

> ```
>       while (num_person != 0)
> ```

---

Similarly, the use of namespaces is inconsistent. Most of the vectors are `vector<int>`, but there's the odd `std::vector<int>` floating about.

Not that `vector<int>` is the clearest way of doing things. It would increase readability (and maybe even performance) to define a struct for the intervals. It would also reduce the potential for confusion of the name `CompareByLength`: when comparing two vectors by length I generally expect the code to look at the length of the vectors, not the difference between their first two values.

---

Coming back to `CompareByLength`:

> ```
>     struct CompareByLength {
>         constexpr bool operator()(vector<int> const & a,
>                                   vector<int> const & b) const noexcept
>         {
>             int aa = (a[1]-a[0])+1;
>             int bb = (b[1]-b[0])+1;
>             return aa < bb;
>
>         }
>     };
> ```

The two `+1` are pointless. But more importantly, there's no tie-breaking. This absolutely needs a comment explaining why it's not necessary to break ties.

---

> ```
>     vector <vector<int>> double_vec = {{1,num_stall}};
>     for (vector<vector<int>>::iterator i = double_vec.begin(); i != double_vec.end(); i++)
>     {
>         qq.push(*i) ;
>     }
> ```

Seems a rather long-winded way to initialise a queue with a single item.

---

> ```
>         int occ = tt[1] - ceil((double(tt[1])-double(tt[0]))/2);
> ```

Why use `tt[1]` and `tt[0]` after pulling them out into variables with intelligible names? And why convert to doubles? Just rewrite as

```
    int occ = left + (right - left) / 2;
```

---

Finally, note that the test data's explanation included an observation:

> > In Case #4, every stall is occupied at the end, no matter what the stall choices are.

So given input

```
1
1000000000000000000 1000000000000000000
```

this code will run for a *very* long time even though I can tell you without running any code that the output should be

```
Case #1: 0 0
```

Do you think this might be a hint that it's not necessary to explicitly work through the sequence of stalls occupied? In fact, you can take it as a golden rule of challenge programming that the constraints

> > - 1 ≤ K ≤ N
> > - 1 ≤ N ≤ 10<sup>18</sup>

mean that you're expected to find a solution which takes o(K) time.